# unable to instantiate CQ.utils.WCM in cq publish mode

Tags: aem

I'm unable to instantiate CQ.utils.WCM in CQ publsih mode to get pagePath using the function CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath(), but I can able to get the pagePath  in CQ Author mode using the same function. Can somebody help me why 
 CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath() function not executing in jsp file in cq publish crxde lite

Thank you for your help!
Naren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because your AEM specific client libraries would not have been included in publish mode (i.e., when `WCMMODE` is `disabled`) and this is an ideal scenario.

The clientlibs might have been included as shown below

```
<% if(WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != WCMMode.DISABLED) { %>
<cq:includeClientLib categories="cq.widgets" />
 <%-- or --%>
<cq:includeClientLib categories="cq.wcm.edit" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: You're Right. Thank you!